# cocos2d-x: read mp3 data from memory

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a encrypted file that packed many mp3 sound tracks, I want to decrypt it while my cocos2d-x game is running and play one specific mp3 as background music without any temp files are generated, but, the api in cocos2d-x can only Accept exsiting .mp3 file on disk, so how do I do to make cocos2d-x read mp3 data that I decrypted in memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not playing from a filepath, you will have to edit the cocos2d-x audio engine source codes.

For example for iOS, the bgm is loaded through the `-(void) load:(NSString*) filePath` function of `CDLongAudioSource` in CDAudioManager.m

```
NSString *path = [CDUtilities fullPathFromRelativePath:audioSourceFilePath];
audioSourcePlayer = [(AVAudioPlayer*)[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
```

It is calling `initWithContentsOfURL` for the `AVAudioPlayer` object. You can either modify this or create a separate function that uses `initWithData` to suit your needs.

As for Android, it seems more complicated. I have traced it down to this `createUrlAudioPlayer(const AudioPlayerProvider::AudioFileInfo &info)` function in AudioPlayerProvider.cpp that is performing the loading from filepath.

**EDIT**:
Another suggestion is not to use their audio engine but write your own class that will implement native platform functions to play audio from data.